# How would you make a comma-separated string from a list of strings?

Tags: python, string, list

What would be your preferred way to concatenate strings from a sequence such that between every two consecutive pairs a comma is added. That is, how do you map, for instance, `['a', 'b', 'c']` to `'a,b,c'`? (The cases `['s']` and `[]` should be mapped to `'s'` and `''`, respectively.)

I usually end up using something like `''.join(map(lambda x: x+',',l))[:-1]`, but also feeling somewhat unsatisfied.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate items in a list to a single string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string)

Answer (score 1310, accepted):

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
my_string = ','.join(my_list)
```

```
'a,b,c,d'
```

This won't work if the list contains integers

---

And if the list contains non-string types (such as integers, floats, bools, None) then do:

```
my_string = ','.join(map(str, my_list))
```

Comment: Note if you are using python 2.7 (which you shouldn't by now) then using str will raise an exception if any item in the list has unicode.

Comment: My requirement, bringing me here, was to fill an SQL "WHERE x NOT IN ()" clause.  The join() function will insert any string you like between elements but does nothing for each end of the list.  So this works:  nameString = '"{}"'.format('", "'.join(nameList)) Those are single quotes enclosing the desired double quoted strings. Python 3.7

Comment: Why does python not have a professional function to perform this operation?

Comment: It's worth noting that this answer was posted over 13 years ago. I'm guessing plenty has changed with Python since then.

Answer (score 94):

Why the `map`/`lambda` magic? Doesn't this work?

```
>>> foo = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> print(','.join(foo))
a,b,c
>>> print(','.join([]))

>>> print(','.join(['a']))
a
```

In case if there are numbers in the list, you could use list comprehension:

```
>>> ','.join([str(x) for x in foo])
```

or a generator expression:

```
>>> ','.join(str(x) for x in foo)
```

Answer (score 29):

`",".join(l)` will not work for all cases. I'd suggest using the csv module with StringIO

```
import StringIO
import csv

l = ['list','of','["""crazy"quotes"and\'',123,'other things']

line = StringIO.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(line)
writer.writerow(l)
csvcontent = line.getvalue()
# 'list,of,"[""""""crazy""quotes""and\'",123,other things\r\n'
```

Comment: There is no `StringIO` in Python 3

Comment: @RonKalian Use `from io import StringIO` in Python 3

Answer (score 19):

@Peter Hoffmann

Using generator expressions has the benefit of also producing an iterator but saves importing itertools. Furthermore, list comprehensions are generally preferred to map, thus, I'd expect generator expressions to be preferred to imap.

```
>>> l = [1, "foo", 4 ,"bar"]
>>> ",".join(str(bit) for bit in l)
'1,foo,4,bar'
```

Comment: Experts, please, tell why isn't this upvoted as the best solution? It works with integers, strings (with 'crazy characters' as well) and it's just 1 line of code. I'm newbie, so I'd like to know the limitations of this method.

Comment: Hi, is there a way where I can let string literals remain as strings in this?

Answer (score 17):

Here is a alternative solution in Python 3.0 which allows non-string list items:

```
>>> alist = ['a', 1, (2, 'b')]
```

- a standard way

  ```
  >>> ", ".join(map(str, alist))
  "a, 1, (2, 'b')"
  ```
- the alternative solution

  ```
  >>> import io
  >>> s = io.StringIO()
  >>> print(*alist, file=s, sep=', ', end='')
  >>> s.getvalue()
  "a, 1, (2, 'b')"
  ```

NOTE: The space after comma is intentional.

Answer (score 14):

Don't you just want:

```
",".join(l)
```

Obviously it gets more complicated if you need to quote/escape commas etc in the values. In that case I would suggest looking at the csv module in the standard library:

https://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Answer (score 11):

```
>>> my_list = ['A', '', '', 'D', 'E',]
>>> ",".join([str(i) for i in my_list if i])
'A,D,E'
```

`my_list` may contain any type of variables. This avoid the result `'A,,,D,E'`.

Answer (score 10):

```
l=['a', 1, 'b', 2]

print str(l)[1:-1]

Output: "'a', 1, 'b', 2"
```

Comment: I think you should point out that unlike the other solutions on this page, you quote strings as well.

Answer (score 7):

@jmanning2k using a list comprehension has the downside of creating a new temporary list. The better solution would be using itertools.imap which returns an iterator

```
from itertools import imap
l = [1, "foo", 4 ,"bar"]
",".join(imap(str, l))
```

Comment: This solution doesn't fulfill the requirements of not adding extra comma for empty string and adding a 'None' with NoneType.

Comment: [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-in-python/9061024#9061024) `str.join` work faster with `list` in comparison to generator

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do the shortcut way :) :

```
','.join([str(word) for word in wordList])
```

But if you want to show off with logic :) :

```
wordList = ['USD', 'EUR', 'JPY', 'NZD', 'CHF', 'CAD']
stringText = ''

for word in wordList:
    stringText += word + ','

stringText = stringText[:-2]   # get rid of last comma
print(stringText)
```

Comment: Why -2 and not -1?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example with list

```
>>> myList = [['Apple'],['Orange']]
>>> myList = ','.join(map(str, [i[0] for i in myList])) 
>>> print "Output:", myList
Output: Apple,Orange
```

More Accurate:-

```
>>> myList = [['Apple'],['Orange']]
>>> myList = ','.join(map(str, [type(i) == list and i[0] for i in myList])) 
>>> print "Output:", myList
Output: Apple,Orange
```

Example 2:-

```
myList = ['Apple','Orange']
myList = ','.join(map(str, myList)) 
print "Output:", myList
Output: Apple,Orange
```

Comment: This question was about lists, not *lists of lists*.

Comment: @EeroAaltonen I updated My answer, Thanks for pointing me to right.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the `csv` library is the only sensible option here, as it was built to cope with all csv use cases such as commas in a string, etc.

To output a list `l` to a .csv file:

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(l)  # this will output l as a single row.
```

It is also possible to use `writer.writerows(iterable)` to output multiple rows to csv.

This example is compatible with Python 3, as the other answer here used `StringIO` which is Python 2.

Comment: But isn't that too much/complicated compared to other answers?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, `','.join(foo)` should do what you're asking for.

```
>>> ','.join([''])
''
>>> ','.join(['s'])
's'
>>> ','.join(['a','b','c'])
'a,b,c'
```

(edit:  and as jmanning2k points out,

```
','.join([str(x) for x in foo])
```

is safer and quite Pythonic, though the resulting string will be difficult to parse if the elements can contain commas -- at that point, you need the full power of the `csv` module, as Douglas points out in his answer.)

Answer (score 0):

mmm also need for SQL is :

```
l = ["foo" , "baar" , 6]
where_clause = "..... IN ("+(','.join([ f"'{x}'" for x in l]))+")"
>> "..... IN ('foo','baar','6')"
```

enjoit

Answer (score -1):

My two cents. I like simpler an one-line code in python:

```
>>> from itertools import imap, ifilter
>>> l = ['a', '', 'b', 1, None]
>>> ','.join(imap(str, ifilter(lambda x: x, l)))
a,b,1
>>> m = ['a', '', None]
>>> ','.join(imap(str, ifilter(lambda x: x, m)))
'a'
```

It's pythonic, works for strings, numbers, None and empty string. It's short and satisfies the requirements. If the list is not going to contain numbers, we can use this simpler variation:

```
>>> ','.join(ifilter(lambda x: x, l))
```

Also this solution doesn't create a new list, but uses an iterator, like @Peter Hoffmann pointed (thanks).

Comment: This is superfluous. The accepted answer is simple, direct and clearly the best solution. To provide overly complex alternatives is a pointless waste of time. If you're merely trying to educate about other features of the language when there is already a viable answers, you're doing the same thing you downvoted me for.