# print some numbers in same line by seperating them with comma

Tags: python, arraylist

I want to print number like 
"Factors of (input_number) are " 1,2,5,10,50
but is printing with an extra comma like this:
         1,2,3,4,5,

```
input_number = int(input("Enter A Number Please: "))
factors = []
for divisor in range(1, input_number+1):
        mod = input_number % divisor
        if mod == 0:
            factors.append(divisor)
print("Factors of %i are - " % input_number)
for element in factors:
        print(element, end=",")
```

Comment: note: the upper limit for your test should be `int(sqrt(input_number)) (+ 1)`. there is no need to go any further.

Comment: This [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438684/how-to-convert-a-list-of-longs-into-a-comma-separated-string-in-python) seems to have your answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a list of longs into a comma separated string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438684/how-to-convert-a-list-of-longs-into-a-comma-separated-string-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you make a comma-separated string from a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44778/how-would-you-make-a-comma-separated-string-from-a-list-of-strings)

Comment: @rovyko The elements are not strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
input_number = int(input("Enter A Number Please: "))
factors = []
for divisor in range(1, input_number+1):
        mod = input_number % divisor
        if mod == 0:
            factors.append(divisor)
print("Factors of %i are - " % input_number+ ",".join(str(row) for row in factors))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print the elements of an iterable with a given separator, you should send that iterable to `print` and unpack it, and use the `sep` argument, rather than printing each element separately with the `end` argument (which, as you saw, puts the given string at the "end" of each element, including the last one).

```
print(*factors, sep=",")
```

Comment: I didn't know that the `sep` keyword argument existed until just now. [Link to documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#print) for others.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, the `end` keyword argument to `print` will specify what should be printed after the string you pass in as the first positional argument. So after each element you print, you're telling Python to print a comma (`,` character) and that's exactly what it is doing.

One way you could do achieve this is by explicitly not setting the `end` keyword argument for the last item in the array using array [enumeration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), like so:

```py
print("Factors: ", end="")
for index, element in enumerate(factors):
    if index == len(factors) - 1:
        print(element)
    else:
        print(element, end=",")
```

Another way you could accomplish this would be to convert your array into strings then use the [`.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method, which concatenates the elements of an iterable with a "glue" string.

```py
print("Factors: ", end="")
factors = map(str, factors)
print(",".join(factors))
```

It may be helpful to note that casting to `str` should not affect the way non-strings are printed to STDOUT because they would implicitly be cast to strings when printing. For the second method, it may be helpful to reference the Python documentation for [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).