# what is making try: exit early?

Tags: python

in the following function, what is making `try:` exit early? If I put the same code outside a `def` block it works fine.

```
tiles = ['095D', '094M']
in_file = 'in_file'
out_file = 'out_file'
expression = ''' "FIELDNAME" LIKE 'STUFF' '''

def foobar(in_file, out_file, expression):
    print in_file, out_file, expression
    try:
        print 'this is trying'
        #pretty print tile list, from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399112/python-print-delimited-list
        tiles = ','.join(map(str,tiles))
        print 'made it past tiles!'
        print 'From %s \nselecting %s \ninto %s' % (in_file, tiles, out_file)

    except:
        print 'Made it to the except block!'

foobar(in_file, out_file, expression)
```

Results:

```
D:\> python xx-debug.py
in_file out_file  "FIELDNAME" LIKE 'STUFF'
this is trying
Made it to the except block!
```

Results with the [same code not in a def](http://pastebin.com/aX1cjpBX):

```
this is trying
made it past tiles!
From in_file
selecting 095D,094M
into out_file
```

Comment: easy there, beginners will do such things.

Comment: @aaronasterling  "Pokemon Exception Handling - Gotta catch'em all!"

Comment: You should not `except:` without specifying an exception. That will also catch things like KeyboardInterrupt which is almost never what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because you defined `tiles` in the global scope. In the function you're assigning to `tiles`. This makes `tiles` a local scoped name in the function. This, in turn, means that the code in the function won't look for `tiles` in the global scope at all.

In the assignment, you're trying to *get* `tiles` (this is before it has been assigned locally.) This results in an exception being raised, since you tried to access an unassigned local variable.

The quick fix is to use `global`:

```
...
def foobar(in_file, out_file, expression):
    global tiles
    ...
```

As others said, don't just catch exceptions without doing something with them. When debugging code, you *want* exceptions to be thrown so you can find and fix the cause! Either remove the `try`...`except`, or make the `except` take an exception and print useful information about it, like this:

```
try:
    ...
except Exception, e:
    print 'Oh noes!', e
```

---

This may be a lot to read, but you will understand Python much better if you do read it:

http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html

It explains how Python handles variable definitions in the module scope and function scopes, etc. It also covers exceptions.

Comment: the real except block is `except:\n\tprint gp.GetMessages()\n` [(ref)](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/body.cfm?tocVisable=1&ID=924&TopicName=Error%20handling%20with%20Python) I took it out when building the simplest possible reproduction of the error. Thanks for cluing me in to what was going on.

Answer (score 3):

Exception output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sof.py", line 19, in <module>
    foobar(in_file, out_file, expression)
  File "sof.py", line 11, in foobar
    tiles = ','.join(map(str,tiles))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tiles' referenced before assignment
```

Now, this happens because tiles is actually defined in the **global** space.  So, your function should look like this:

```
def foobar(in_file, out_file, expression):
    global tiles
    ...
```

Comment: You should probably explain that it's happening because `tiles` is defined locally in the function, which means that any global variable will be ignored unless you use the `global` keyword. This error would happen even if you didn't define `tiles` globally.

Comment: how did you get that UnboundLocalError message? All I get is silence.

Comment: `except` swallows the exception. Without `except` you would get that error.

Answer (score -1):

That's an interesting bug you have. So there's a module-scoped `tiles` outside the function, and since you're not using `global`, you're creating a new `tiles` variable inside the function. This is fine. Or it would be fine, except that it appears (when I mess around in interactive Python) that the lvalue of the statement (the `tiles` on the left) being local, makes the entire statement think that any reference to tiles means the local one. So in that map construct, instead of using the module `tites` it uses the local one, except the local one doesn't exist yet.

This may be a bug in Python, but probably it's as-intended.

Comment: Not a bug, it's very well-defined in fact. There's a difference between global and local variables. It's cases like these that you have the `global` keyword for. :)

Comment: Right but you'd think it would evaluate the right side first using (as far as it knows at that point) global scope, then create a local variable and assign to that. It appears that Python scans ahead to see if a local variable by that name is ever created.