# Fibonacci series in order, with first n numbers, without spaces, just with commas, like 1,1,2,3,5

Tags: python, fibonacci

It should look like 1,1,2,3,5 but i can't find out how to do print like this, i've tried with .join but it's not working.

```
fib_b = int(input("Fibonacci number? "))
def fib():
    if n<=1:
       return 1
    else:
       return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
fibs= [fib(i) for i in range(fib_n)]
**print (fibs)**
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What you are looking for seems similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399112/python-print-delimited-list).
Please check if this answers your query.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to provide the actual information here and not just a link. [Link-only answers are not considered good answers and will probably be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).