# converting mongodb values in query to a string in python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

How can I convert the values in the multiple responses from mongodb in python to a string with the values separated by a comma?

I don't know if my question is understandable, basically, this is what I want to do.

I am using this code to get data from mongodb:

```
    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
    mydb = myclient["mydatabase"]
    driversdb = mydb["orders"]

    ordersQuery = { "city": city }
    mydoc = ordersdb.find(ordersQuery)
    for x in mydoc:
```

The response is:

```
{ <more values>, 'orderid': 'IHZXMZQ3SX', <more values> }
{ <more values>, 'orderid': 'eu8j35tvoO', <more values> }
<more data>
```

how can I convert that to:

```
orderslist = "IHZXMZQ3SX, eu8j35tvoO, <more orderids>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can be extracted in one line

```
orderids = [x['orderid'] for x in mydoc]
```

Comment: It works but I get: "orders": [
    "IHZXMZQ3SX", 
    "eu8j35tvoO"
  ]

Comment: you wanted a list right ? and the list has all the order id's right ? or did i misread the question ?

Comment: It gets the job done, but I need to remove the extra characters

Comment: maybe you need to learn the string method join, as in ','.join(['a','b','c'])

Comment: Do as above and then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44778/how-would-you-make-a-comma-separated-string-from-a-list-of-strings

Comment: hey, I am using this method but when I add it twice (two lists for two values) the second one is empty. if I comment the one on top the second one works. How can I fix this?

Comment: can you elaborate ? may be some example will do.?

Comment: If I add orderNames = [x['ordername'] for x in mydoc] and orders = [x['orderid'] for x in mydoc] one on top of the other orderNames gets the values from mongodb and orders is empty (i.e. orders = [])

Comment: yes.. it's because the cursor moved forward. before using orders = [...],  use mydoc.rewind() to reset the cursor to initial position