# Hey I want to send email to more than one person with python

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail

Hey i want to send an email to a bunch of people but for some reason even if the output of print is more than one email the program sending the email only to first person of the text what can i do ?

```
# Import Python Packages
import smtplib
# Set Global Variables
gmail_user = 'your@gmail.com'
gmail_password = 'password'
# Create Email 
mail_from = gmail_user

for i in range(2):
  with open('C:\\email.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8") as f
      mail_to = f.read().rstrip()
      
  mail_subject = 'subject'
  mail_message_body = 'body'

  mail_message = '''\
  From: %s
  To: %s
  Subject: %s
  %s
  ''' % (mail_from, mail_to, mail_subject, mail_message_body)
  # Sent Email
  server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
  server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
  server.sendmail(mail_from, mail_to, mail_message)
  print(mail_to)
server.close()
```

Comment: What is the contents of the file 'email.txt'?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail

Answer (score 1):

Send_to must be a string object having addresses separated by ", ".

example  :

```
send_to='xyz1@gmail.com,hhdasn@yahoo.com'
```

Comment: but the emails are inside the txt

Comment: See question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44778/how-would-you-make-a-comma-separated-string-from-a-list-of-strings for how to create comma-separated string

Comment: the problem is not to send the email is to change the email of the receiver

Answer (score 0):

The line that performs sending of email is `server.sendmail(mail_from, mail_to, mail_message)`. You are calling it once. You can check it by placing `print(mail_to)` statement next to it.

You need to call `sendmail` in loop if you want to send email multiple times.

Comment: Now you are creating server and logging in several times. But I think that adding emails to `mail_to` as comma-separated list is a better solution, as Vikas Jain suggets