# Discord Python Bot Multiple Value in embed field

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-3.9

So i have a discord bot (using python) that connect to a sqlite database, and i want to show the data using embed. The data is containing my daily anime schedule.

Here's the code :

```
@commands.command(aliases=['Schedule'])
    async def schedule(self, ctx, day = None):
        if (day==None):
            conn = sqlite3.connect('./cogs/animelist.db')
            cursor1 = conn.execute("SELECT name, status_eps from Animelist where day = 'monday'")
            cursor2 = conn.execute("SELECT name, status_eps from Animelist where day = 'tuesday'")
            cursor3 = conn.execute("SELECT name, status_eps from Animelist where day = 'wednesday'")
            cursor4 = conn.execute("SELECT name, status_eps from Animelist where day = 'thursday'")
            cursor5 = conn.execute("SELECT name, status_eps from Animelist where day = 'friday'")
            cursor6 = conn.execute("SELECT name, status_eps from Animelist where day = 'saturday'")
            cursor7 = conn.execute("SELECT name, status_eps from Animelist where day = 'sunday'")

            embed = discord.Embed(
                title=f'Anime Schedule:',
                colour=discord.Color.blue())

            for row in cursor1:
                embed.add_field(name=f'Monday', value=f'{row[0]} (Eps : {row[1]})', inline=False)
            for row in cursor2:
                embed.add_field(name=f'Tuesday', value=f'{row[0]} (Eps : {row[1]})', inline=False)
            for row in cursor3:
                embed.add_field(name=f'Wednesday', value=f'{row[0]} (Eps : {row[1]})', inline=False)
            for row in cursor4:
                embed.add_field(name=f'Thursday', value=f'{row[0]} (Eps : {row[1]})', inline=False)
            for row in cursor5:
                embed.add_field(name=f'Friday', value=f'{row[0]} (Eps : {row[1]})', inline=False)
            for row in cursor6:
                embed.add_field(name=f'Saturday', value=f'{row[0]} (Eps : {row[1]})', inline=False)
            for row in cursor7:
                embed.add_field(name=f'Sunday',value=f'{row[0]} (Eps : {row[1]})',inline=False)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            conn.close()
```

The problem is this
[Discord Embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1xfA.png)

There are 2 'Sunday' which is not what i wanted. What i want is (example for Sunday), the 'Value' will showing 'aot (eps :)'\n'wataten (eps :)'
So that the result will showing this :

```
Sunday :
aot (eps : )
wataten (eps : )
```

I try to write this

```
Value=f'{for row in cursor7:
                 {row[0]}\n}'
```

So that for every row in cursor 7, it will automatically creating a new line. But i know it wont working.
Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example, you can do

```
sunday_episodes = "\n".join([f"{row[0]} (Eps : {row[1]})" for row in cursor7])
```

See: [How would you make a comma-separated string from a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44778/how-would-you-make-a-comma-separated-string-from-a-list-of-strings)

Comment: It should be `f'{row[0]} (Eps : {row[1]})'` instead of just `row[1]`. OP also mentioned that they wanted to use newlines, so `'\n'.join(...)` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help effprime and ZeroKnight , it doesn't help directly actually, but I've managed to solve the problem by creating a new database. Of course, by using the code above. Once again, thank you so much