# How do I append a value to an existing string and make print in 1 output line in python?

Tags: python

I'm a student and I was tasked to write a program to print out the leap years found based on the input of 2 years entered by a user. For example, if the user enters 1989 and 2000. It will find the leap year that occurs within 1989 and 2000. My code will be executed in the python terminal.

e.g Sample input is

```
python LeapYearCalculator.py 1989 2000
```

However, I'm not sure how to append the year that is a leap year to my print statement. How do I do this?

Current output of my program is, which is wrong as I also want to append the leap years 1992 and 1996. The next set of code is the output I want.

```
The number of Leap Years is 3, the Leap Years are 2000
```

But expected output is

```
The number of Leap Years is 3, the Leap Years are 1992, 1996, 2000
```

My code is below

```
import sys

try:


    startYear = sys.argv[1]
    endYear = sys.argv[2]
    startYear = int(startYear)
    endYear = int(endYear)

    numOfLeapYear = int()
    leapYearList = []

    for year in range(startYear,endYear+1,1):
        if (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or (year % 400 == 0):
            numOfLeapYear = numOfLeapYear + 1
            leapYearList.append(year)
            #for i in range (len(leapYearList)):
    print("The number of Leap Years is %i, the Leap Years are %i" % (numOfLeapYear, year))
except:
    print("Your input is invalid")
```

Comment: You are not filling `leapYearList`, you should. Why is it there?

Comment: You do not print anything from `leapYearList`. Why fill a list and not use it?

Comment: Your try-except is really bad style, any kind of error could occur, which you are hiding by your `except` as a "Your input is invalid". As a beginner, try to *not* use exception handling unless you absolutely have or need to, and even then only use it very locally at the point where a *specific* exception is expected to occur, and catch the specific exception. You are making learning Python much harder for yourself otherwise.

Comment: Look into  `print(','.join(leapYearList))` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44778/how-would-you-make-a-comma-separated-string-from-a-list-of-strings

Answer (score 0):

Sample solution (see code comments for what was changed):

```py
try:
    startYear = "1989"
    endYear = "2000"
    startYear = int(startYear)
    endYear = int(endYear)

    numOfLeapYear = int()
    leapYearList = []

    for year in range(startYear, endYear+1, 1):
        if (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or (year % 400 == 0):
            numOfLeapYear = numOfLeapYear + 1
            leapYearList.append(str(year))  # 1. added casting year to str
    print(
        "The number of Leap Years is %i, the Leap Years are %s"  # 2. changed %i to %s
        % (
            numOfLeapYear,
            ", ".join(leapYearList)  # 3. added join
        )
    )
except:
    print("Your input is invalid")
```

1. `year` is now cast to `str` before appending to `leapYearList`, so that we can `", ".join(...)` the list later
2. the `%i` was changed to `%s` because the placeholder is going to be replaced with a string, not an integer; the %-formatting is kind of old school by the way, I would recommend using f-strings or str.format, e.g. `f"number of Leap Years is {numOfLeapYear}"` or `"number of Leap Years is {}".format(numOfLeapYear)`
3. previously, only the last value of `year` was printed, now we print the entire `leapYearList` with its values separated by a comma and a space

Output:

```
The number of Leap Years is 3, the Leap Years are 1992, 1996, 2000
```